# What is the difference between parentheses () and square brackets [] when enclosing real-time interjections in the Kane Chronicles?

Tags: orthography, rick-riordan

The conceit that each of the books of the Kane Chronicles is a transcription of an audio recording allows frequent interjections from current-time Sadie and Carter, commenting on the past events or on each others' narration. These interjections are always enclosed in parentheses `()` or `[]` brackets. I had not noticed any difference between the two, and indeed had not really considered the variation at all, until I came to this passage:

> Our footsteps echoed in the silent tunnels. We crossed one of the subterranean rivers, then wound our way through the library quarter and the Chamber of Birds.
>
> (Carter says I should tell you why it's called that. It's a cave full of all sorts of birds. Again—*duh*. [Carter, why are you banging your head against the table?])
> <sub>*The Serpent's Shadow*, Chapter 6: "Amos Plays with Action Figures"</sub>

From the same chapter I find instances where only one of the two enclosing symbol types were used.

> Apparently I'd made a strong impression on the young man. No surprise. I am rather memorable.
>
> [Oh, stop laughing, Carter.]

> Of course, I had to hope my portal didn't open during an *inauspicious* moment. That could have caused all sorts of nasty side effects—but what's life without taking a few risks?
>
> (Carter is shaking his head and muttering. I have no idea why.)

Clearly there is some distinction, or it would be unnecessary to use both kinds of symbols in so short a passage. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized the answer in the process of writing the question. Square brackets enclose statements addressed to Carter, while parentheses enclose statements addressed to the reader (or, I guess, *listener*, going by the conceit). For completeness, Carter follows a similar convention. These quotes are from Chapter 4, "I Consult the Pigeon of War".

> The thing was, I'd gotten used to his being around. Now that he spent most of his time with the kindergartners, I missed him. He'd grown on me in an endearing, annoying way, kind of like my sister.
>
> [Yeah, Sadie. You saw that one coming.]

> I was still mad, but part of me knew Sadie was right. I'd expended a lot of magical energy the previous night and had gone to sleep really late. Maybe—just maybe—Sadie had my best interests at heart.
>
> (I just caught her making faces at me, so maybe not.)